# Django Ajax 405 (Method Not Allowed) CBV

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, http-status-code-405

I'm having trouble in POST-ing and DELETE-ing through Ajax call ! 
I've defined the methods on class! idk what is happening.

Any help will be appreciated

urls.py:

```
 path('<section>/add_wish/<slug>/', views.AddToWishlistView.as_view(), name='add_to_cart'),
```

my view :

```
class AddToWishlistView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    model = Wishlist
    http_method_names = ['POST']

    def POST(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      wished_product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
      new_item = self.model.objects.get(customer = self.request.user)
      new_item.product.add(wished_product)
      return HttpResponse(status=201)
```

and Ajax here !

```
    $('.buy').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let _this = $(this);
        var slug = _this.children().data('id');
        var section_slug = _this.data('section');

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url :  '../'+section_slug + '/add_wish/' + slug + '/',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.success = true){
                    _this.addClass('clicked');
                }

            },
            async : false,
            error : function(data){
                console.log("ERROR");
                console.log(data);
                alert('LOOSERR');
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: the method name must be in lower case. ie, **`def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):`**

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Still not working 405 :/

Comment: HTTP post should work now **if your URL is correct**

Comment: are you sure that the url in jQuery should start with "`../`"  ?

Comment: yeah..the url is correct

Comment: @alan_jouhar if the url is incorrect it will show 404. right ?

Answer (score 0):

The method name should be the lower case:

```py
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Every request coming to the view goes thru the `dispatch` method which is responsible for calling the correct method. Here is explained how it works:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch

and here is the source code:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/291539a85c8461456ab728fe6820a86de54294b6/django/views/generic/base.py#L93-L101